# GLFW functions "undefined" (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, glfw

For some reason whenever I try to run my code, I keep getting the same error that says the functions I'm trying to use are "undefined".

I put my glfw3.h file at `C:\WinGW\Include\GLFW\glfw3.h` and glfw3.dll at `C:\Window\System32\glfw3.dll`

here's my code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I want it to create a window which is 640 by 480 pixels, but instead I get this output:

````
C:\Users\EMIELN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUSxbbl.o:main.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to 'glfwInit'
C:\Users\EMIELN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUSxbbl.o:main.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to 'glfwCreateWindow'
C:\Users\EMIELN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUSxbbl.o:main.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to 'glfwTerminate'
C:\Users\EMIELN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUSxbbl.o:main.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to 'glfwMakeContextCurrent'
C:\Users\EMIELN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUSxbbl.o:main.c:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to '_imp__glClear@4'
C:\Users\EMIELN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUSxbbl.o:main.c:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to 'glfwSwapBuffers'
C:\Users\EMIELN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUSxbbl.o:main.c:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to 'glfwPollEvents'
C:\Users\EMIELN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUSxbbl.o:main.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to 'glfwWindowShouldClose'
C:\Users\EMIELN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUSxbbl.o:main.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to 'glfwTerminate'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status```
````

Comment: You must add the import library `glfw3.lib` to the linker.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: oh nevermind, I figured it out already, but it still doesnt work??

Comment: @pigeoni2 -- if it still doesn't work then it might be best to open a new question for the new problem -- this avoids confusion and mess.